# How to get address using longitude and latitude

Tags: java, blackberry, latitude-longitude

I am using Geocoding .I want to get address or location using longitude and latitude .But when I used **bedford** .It is showing **Atlantic ocean** every time.

```
package mypackage;
import javax.microedition.location.AddressInfo;
import javax.microedition.location.Landmark;

import net.rim.device.api.lbs.Locator;
import net.rim.device.api.lbs.LocatorException;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class myReverseGeocode extends MainScreen
{
    private Thread reverseGeocode;

    public myReverseGeocode()
    {
        reverseGeocode = new Thread(thread);
        reverseGeocode.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        reverseGeocode.start();
    }

    Runnable thread = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            AddressInfo addrInfo = null;

            int latitude  = (int)(52.135973);
            int longitude = (int)(-0.466655);

            try
            {
                Landmark[] results = Locator.reverseGeocode
                 (latitude, longitude, Locator.ADDRESS );

                if ( results != null && results.length > 0 )
                    addrInfo = results[0].getAddressInfo();

                synchronized(Application.getEventLock())
                {
                       add(new LabelField("------------------------"+addrInfo));
              add(new LabelField("------------------------"+addrInfo.getField(addrInfo.BUILDING_FLOOR)));
              add(new LabelField("------------------------"+addrInfo.getField(addrInfo.CITY)));
              add(new LabelField("------------------------"+addrInfo.hashCode()));
              add(new LabelField("------------------------"+addrInfo.getField(addrInfo.BUILDING_NAME)));
              add(new LabelField("------------------------"+addrInfo.getField(addrInfo.COUNTRY)));
              add(new LabelField("------------------------"+addrInfo.getField(addrInfo.STREET)));


                }
          //      add(new LabelField("---"+addrInfo));
            }
            catch ( LocatorException lex )
            {

                  synchronized(Application.getEventLock())
                  {

                      System.out.print("EVENT THREAD\n");
                      Dialog.inform("Posted!"+lex);
                  }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Even if Mister Smith's answer wasn't correct, which it is, you couldn't possibly expect to get reasonable results by rounding lat/long values in *degrees* to an integer degree value (which is what casting to an int does).  One degree spans a very large distance.

Answer (score 2):

That [reverseGeocode](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/Locator.html#reverseGeocode%28int,%20int,%20int%29) method takes two ints as parameters, but these are "*decimal degrees to five decimal places, multiplied by 100000*" according to the docs.

Just create a new `Coordinates` instance and use the second version of that method:

```
    Coordinates coords = new Coordinates(52.135973, -0.466655, 0);
    Landmark[] results = Locator.reverseGeocode(coords, Locator.ADDRESS );
```